# Only direct subclasses must implement method

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I'm programming a zoo simulator (my favorite example when dealing with inheritance). I've got a general `Animal` class. Then I have two classes that `extend Animal` called `Bird` and another one called `LandAnimal`. All subclasses of `Bird` will move in the same way (I'm not planning on having any ostriches in my zoo!), and likewise with `LandAnimal`. Therefore, I made a `move()` method in the `Animal` class. But birds and land animals move so differently that I didn't want to add anything to the method. So I marked it `abstract` overlooking the fact that all subclasses of `Bird` are going to have to implement it. This didn't seem good to me, even if the code was just

```
@Override
public void move()
{
    super.move();
}
```

It still doesn't feel right to have that in every file.

The main question is: Is there any way for me to make only *direct* subclass implement a method (`Bird` has to but the `Sparrow extends Bird` class doesn't)?

Edit: I have overlooked something relating to my simulator. I would rather not have 3 different lists to iterate over and call `move()` on them. I would like to have one `ArrayList<Animal>` that I can use for updating and drawing.

Comment: Yes; just implement it in `Bird` only.

Comment: If you implement the `move()` method in `Bird` then subclasses can choose to override it again but *don't have* to.  Your statement that they do is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you implement the `move()` method in `Bird` and `Sparrow` doesn't have to change it, then you don't have to implement it in `Sparrow`, it'll be inherited as-is *without* the need to re-implement it to only call `super.move();`. That's the whole idea of inheritance: in the subclasses you reuse the code from the superclasses and only add or override methods in those cases when the behaviour is different from the parent's.

Comment: @BitNinja That's all right, an `ArrayList<Animal>` can contain instances of any of its concrete subclasses (no matter how deep down in the hierarchy), and as long as you stick to calling methods that exist in `Animal`, you can add all of the zoo in the same list and invoke methods on the objects contained in the list. That's the power of polymorphism in action - which works together with inheritance

Comment: Am I allowed to do `for (Bird bird : animals)` where `animals` is an `ArrayList<Animal>` even though some of the items in `animals` might not be `Birds`?

Comment: @BitNinja nope, but you're allowed to do `for (Animal animal : animals)`

Comment: But that's the problem. If I understood your answer correctly, that method wouldn't even exist in the `Animal` class.

Comment: @BitNinja what method? `move()` _exists_ in `Animal` class, even if it's not implemented there. And when you fill the list, you do it with concrete subclasses that _do_ implement it, so it can be called. Why don't you try it? it'll be much, much better if you construct an actual example and see how things work.

Answer (score 0):

If `Bird` implements the method and `Sparrow` extends `Bird`, then `Sparrow` has an implementation; it doesn't need to provide another one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- for `abstract` methods (and interface methods, which are the same thing), each class must implement all of them, but super classes that implement them count as valid. So if `Bird` implements the abstract `move` method, `Sparrow` doesn't have to because its parent class already implemented it.